# React Native - Passing state to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having some trouble with passing state.

I want to get state from `EventsApi` passed to `Event`.

Here's my parent component:

```
export default class EventsApi extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

    this.state = {
     jsondata: ["TEST1"],
 };
} 
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Event data={this.state.jsondata} />
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

And here is my child component:

```
export default class Event extends React.PureComponent {

render() {

return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.jsondata}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <NormalText>
          {item}
        </NormalText>
      )}
    />
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `{item}` in event is empty. I make a call on `Event` in a view class simply as: `<Event></Event>`. So it goes from `EventsApi` -> `Events` as shown and then to `ViewClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are doing wrong is you are passing Event in your App.js it should be EventsApi:

change

```
<View>
      <Event></Event>
    </View>
```

to

```
<View>
      <EventsApi></EventsApi>
    </View>
```

made some changes to your expo check this: https://snack.expo.io/nTBUaDxOO

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The thing I didn't get, was how it wen't from parent -> child -> view.

Answer (score 1):

replace your jsondata with data in event as below .because you'r passing your state as data in props.

```
<FlatList
      data={this.props.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <NormalText>
          {item}
        </NormalText>
      )}
    />
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I simply don't get why it's not working. Tried a lot of things so far.
What I forgot to mention, is that I call `Event` in a view class like this `<Event></Event>`, could that cause any issues? Like it losses state or something?

Comment: is it necessary to wrap View class ?

Comment: In this case yes. Because `EventsApi` is my fetch - just trying the simplify the issue, and then I style the `Event` component, to finally be rendered in a view class, with a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: Could problem be in the `NormalText` component?

Comment: @M4RXX can you please share your console.log(this.props) in Event or share codesandbox url please .

Comment: Just tested, `NormalText` isn't the issue. It's just a styled `<Text>`.

Comment: The console.log(this.props) tells me that props is an object and if I do a `toString()` I get `[object Object]`